# python find half time between two times

Tags: python

I want to find half time between two times in python. Let's say I've two times

```
start_time = '08:30:00'
end_time = '16:30:00'
```

If I want to display first half, it should print as`'08:30:00' and '12:30:00'`
If I want to display second half, it should print as `'12:30:00' and '16:30:00'`

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: use `datetime` class. check its usage..

Answer (score 1):

Use a python [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

start_time = '08:30:00'
end_time = '16:30:00'
time_format = '%H:%M:%S'

# Convert to the datetime object
start = datetime.strptime(start_time, time_format)
end = datetime.strptime(end_time, time_format)

# Find half of delta between start and end
half_seconds = (end - start).total_seconds() / 2
half = start + timedelta(seconds=half_seconds)

print(half.strftime(time_format))
print(end.strftime(time_format))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '08:30:00'
b = '16:30:00'
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
delta = datetime.strptime(b, FMT) - datetime.strptime(a, FMT)
half = datetime.strptime(a, FMT) + delta/2
print a + ' - ' + str(datetime.time(half))
print str(datetime.time(half)) + ' - ' + b
```